# Passing multiple jar files in dcos spark-submit, jars with comma separated not suitable

Tags: apache-spark, dcos

uggestions needed, need to pass lots of jar files to dcos spark submit, jars with comma separated not suitable:

Tried below options:

```
dcos spark run --submit-args='--class com.gre.music.inn.orrd.SpaneBasicApp --jars /spark_submit_jobs/new1/unzip_new/* 30'

dcos spark run --submit-args='--class com.gre.music.inn.orrd.SpaneBasicApp --jars local:* 30'

dcos spark run --submit-args='--class com.gre.music.inn.orrd.SpaneBasicApp --jars https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gmu_jars/* 30‘ .
```

The last one wont work bcz I guess wild card is not allowed with http.

Answer (score 1):

Update from DC/OS:

--jars isn't supported via `dcos spark run` (Spark cluster mode).  We'll have support for it around ~ DC/OS 1.10 when we move Spark over to Marathon instead of the Spark dispatcher.  In the mean time, if you want to use --jars, you'll have to submit your job in client mode via spark-submit through metronome or marathon.

Comment: yeah, tried --jars but not avail, now i have to upload my jar file to a http server everytime i want to test on live spark server

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't use wildcards, and you need to put the JARs somewhere where Spark can access them in a distributed manner (S3, http, hdfs, etc.).

See

- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

> `application-jar`: Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use wildcards with `--jars` argument in `spark-submit`. [Here's](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3451) the feature request for that (it's still open).